# Webpack 'not a valid Win32 application' when using Gradle Exec task on Windows

Tags: gradle, webpack

I have the following gradle task per [this](https://guides.gradle.org/running-webpack-with-gradle/)...

```
task webpack(type: Exec) {
    commandLine "./node_modules/.bin/webpack"
}
```

But when I try to run the `gradle webpack` I get the following...

```
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "./node_modules/.bin/webpack"
 (in directory "H:\Code\moxie_db_jpa"): CreateProcess error=193, %1 is not a val
id Win32 application
        at net.rubygrapefruit.platform.internal.DefaultProcessLauncher.start(Def
aultProcessLauncher.java:25)
        ... 5 more
Caused by: java.io.IOException: CreateProcess error=193, %1 is not a valid Win32
 application
        ... 6 more
```

If I run `.\node_modules\.bin\webpack` everything works fine.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this :

```
import org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.condition.Os

task webpack(type: Exec) {
    commandLine './node_modules/.bin/' + (Os.isFamily(Os.FAMILY_WINDOWS) ? 'webpack.cmd' : 'webpack')
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Wow this is weird and although I have an answer, I am not sure it is a good one.

We build on both Windows and Li/Unix machines. This means that Gradle commands need to run on both. Problem is it appears for Li/Unix you need...

```
task webpack(type: Exec) {
    commandLine "./node_modules/.bin/webpack"
}
```

while Windows needs

```
task webpack(type: Exec) {
    commandLine "./node_modules/.bin/webpack.cmd"
}
```

:-(

Now I need to figure out change if Windows.

Comment: you should edit your question and add this into it, and then delete this answer

Comment: Not sure I understand this was the answer but it isn't a good one basically the same one you gave only refactored.